# In React-native, how to handle checkbox in Listview?

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview

In my react-native app, I am trying to show my contact details with checkboxes for selecting.

Here is my code:

```js
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.goRideDetails(rowData)}>
            <Text style={styles.rideHeader}>{rowData.name} </Text>
            <CheckBox
                checked={this.state.checked}
                onCheckBoxPressed={() =>
                    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })
                }
            />
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )}
/>
```

In my view checkbox is displaying on every row, but not working.

Any one can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting each row to have its own checkbox state so that each rows box can be checked/unchecked individually? What do you mean by "...but not working"... what IS it doing?

Comment: thanks for response, Yes I want, exactly what you said. Checkbox state is not updating and checkbox is not checked/unchecked when I press on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with component separation. Please, take a look here:

```
export default class ContactList extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        contacts: React.PropTypes.array,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        contacts: [],
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
    }

    _renderRow(rowData,sectionID,rowID) {
        return <Contact info={ rowData } />;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
              dataSource={ this.props.contacts }
              renderRow={ this._renderRow }  
            />
        );
    }
}

export  class ContactList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        info: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.goRideDetails = this.goRideDetails.bind(this);
        this.setChecked = this.setChecked.bind(this);
    }

    goRideDetails() {
        //your logic here
    }

    setChecked() {
        this.props.info.checked = !this.props.info.checked; //will be much better to do it with redux and action creators
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.goRideDetails }>
                <Text style={ styles.rideHeader }>{this.props.info.name} </Text> 
                <CheckBox checked={ this.props.info.checked } onCheckBoxPressed={ this.setChecked }  />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}
```

After that you can simply call:

```
<ContactList contacts={this.state.dataSource} />
```

in your jsx and voila.

Important note: Do not use array functions inside your jsx code blocks.

Important note 2: Try to start using redux or flux for storing state of your application. It will be provide much better code design.

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Hi Alex Belets, Thanks for answers, but checkbox is not checked/unchecked.I mean when I given flase to initially, checkbox shown with unchecked and when I press/click on it, the value of checkbox  is changed to true but still checkbox shown with unchecked.

Comment: I did some changes in  setChecked method like {this.setState({checked:!this.state.checked}). Now working fine. thank you so much Alex

Comment: Hi Neelima, what changes you had done to update the UI for check/uncheck. Can you please help? I am really stuck into this.

Answer (score 0):

```
            import React , {Component} from 'react'
            import {
                Text,
                View,
                ListView,
                StyleSheet,
                TouchableOpacity,
                Image,
            } from 'react-native'

            import CheckBox from 'react-native-checkbox'

            var Folder = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}) 
            var folder = '' ////// all the new folder
            var check_folder = [] ////// all the check box conditions

            class ApproveContent extends Component {

                ///////// all the upper thing that are global variable for this script is has same value as that of the state the only reason we are using this because of the layout update //////////
                state={
                    folder:[],
                    data:[],
                    check:[]/////// this need to do just to upadte the layout of the check box
                }


                render(){
                    return(

                        <View style = {{flex:1,backgroundColor:'white',alignItems:'center'}}>

                        <ListView
                                dataSource={Folder.cloneWithRows(this.state.folder)}
                                renderRow={(rowData,rowID,sectionID) => <View style = {{ alignItems: 'center',margin:5}}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style = {{width:Dimension.ScreenWidth/1.2,height:Dimension.ScreenHeight/6,flexDirection: 'row',alignItems:'center'}}
                                onPress={() => {}}>
                                <CheckBox
                                 label=''
                                 labelBefore={false}
                                 checked={this.state.check[sectionID]}
                                 checkboxStyle = {{marginLeft: 20}}
                                 onChange={(checked) => {
                                 this.setState({
                                 check:!this.state.check
                                                })
                                 if(check_folder[sectionID] == false){
                                 check_folder[sectionID] = true
                                 this.setState({
                                                check:check_folder// has to do this because  we cant change the single element in the array
                                                })
                                }else{
                                check_folder[sectionID] = false
                                this.setState({
                                check:check_folder// has to do this because  we cant change the single element in the array
                                              })
                                     }
                                console.log(check_folder)a
                                 }}
                                />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                 </View>
                                }
                            />

                        </View>
                    )}
            }

            export default ApproveContent

            const style = StyleSheet.create({

                TextStyle:{
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
                    fontSize:15,
                },
                approveButton: {
                    bottom:0,
                    left:0,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    }


            })
```